# Reset timecode in source footage to 00:00:00

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, adobe, timecode

I have an MOV footage clip supplied by a freelancer that starts timecode at 11:48:09.

It's a standalone clip that I don't need to retain that timecode for.

Would be very useful to reset it to  00:00:00.

Is there any way of doing this in any of the CC apps, FCPX or freeware utilities/apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, like so

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy -map 0 -dn output.mov
```

The `-c copy` sees that there's no re-encoding, the `-map 0` copies everything over but the `-dn` disables data tracks - the timecode being a data track.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this upon export from Premiere.

Load up your clip, export timeline (use Cineform or Prores for lossless if you'll be re-inserting into another project), and click the "Set Start Timecode" checkbox.

[image]